# Getting 404 when Access post which name start with Digit

Tags: permalinks, 404-error

I am facing some strange issue with post pages/

**Getting Error for URL :**

```
www.example.com/5-reasons-to-use-wordpress
```

**Working fine it I change post name like [5 to five] :**

```
www.example.com/five-reasons-to-use-wordpress
```

So issue is when My post name starts with digit , I am getting 404 error.

Comment: But it's working here in my install. Please ensure [basic debugging](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tags/debug/info) and let's know if you get any changes.

Comment: @MayeenulIslam - Ok let me try for basic debugging.